# calling setTitle() method in MainActivity from another class

Tags: android

I would like to change title bar of main activity from another class.
In this second class i check if username and password entered are correct (online check).

Now, when entered correctly, i would like to change title bar to include username.

Problem is that method "setTitle()" isn't static, and therefore cannot be called from second class.

I can change a static variable in main activity, but then how can i check for changes?

I can also put setter for this variable, but it has to be static so "setTitle()" cannot be called from there.

Thanks for any help

Regards

Comment: Did another class you mean is a `Fragment`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom title.

You can try this.

This is mytitle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:orientation="horizontal" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Kredi"
        style="@style/litleTitleStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is main.java

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);
TextView krdTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Kredi);
krdTxt.settext("This is title Text");
```

You can use this code in first or second class

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity class you can create you can create a function like this

```
private void setapptitle(String s){
    this.setTitle(s);
}
```

Then create a handler like this in your main activity class (in the code given below main activity class is MainActivity) and pass this handler to other classes or threads from where you want to set the app title

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(){


            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

                final String title = (String) msg.obj;
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        setapptitle(title);
                    }
                });
                super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        };
```

then you can send message object to this handler from other threads or classes you have passed this handler into. this little snippet down can do the required

```
Message msg = Message.obtain();
msg.obj = your_required_string();
handler.sendMessage(msg);
```